# 2 different answers, two different intuitions for Seattle raining probability problem, which one is correct? and why?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

> You are waiting for your flight to Seattle, and to pass the time you
> call 3 friends in Seattle. You independently ask each one if it is
> raining.
>
> All 3 of your friends say “Yes, it is raining.”
>
> But each friend lies with probability $1/3$ and tells the truth with
> probability $2/3$ (independently).
>
> Can you solve for probability it is actually raining today in Seattle?

**Solution A (Bayesian approach)**

Lets using $P(rain)$ to denote the prior probability of raining in Seattle, $P(dry)=1-P(rain)$ is the prior probability of Seattle stays dry, and $P(y,y,y)$ is the probability of getting 3 “Yes” answers from your friends.

The probability of rain given 3 “Yes” answers is

$$
\begin{align*}
P(rain|y,y,y)&=\frac{P(rain)\cap P(y,y,y)}{P(y,y,y)}\\ &=\frac{P(y,y,y|rain)P(rain)}{P(y,y,y|rain)P(rain)+P(y,y,y|dry)P(dry)}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Set $P(rain)=p$, then $P(dry)=1-p$, the above formula becomes:

$$
\begin{align*}\frac{(2/3)^3\cdot p}{(2/3)^3\cdot p+(1/3)^3\cdot (1-p)}&=\frac{8p/27}{8p/27+(1-p)/27}\\&=\frac{8p}{7p+1}
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore the probability of raining today in Seattle is $8p/(7p+1)$.




**Solution B (Conditional probability with Logic)**

Since you don’t have access to the actual historical raining data in Seattle (prior probability), you need to give the **best estimation** based on **information you’ve given** (currently the sole information source are your friends’ answers).

There’s $2/3\cdot2/3\cdot2/3=8/27$ chance **they’re all telling the truth**.

And $1/3\cdot1/3\cdot1/3=1/27$ chance **they’re all lying.**

By logic, they’re either all telling the truth or all lying, there’s impossible 2 of them are lying and 1 of them telling the truth (Contradiction).

From your perspective, the answer from your friends (Yes or No) and the weather status today in Seattle (Rain or Dry) are **perfectly dependent**: If they’re all telling the truth, then it’s definitely raining, and it’s dry if they’re all lying.

So the probability of **It’s raining and they’re all telling the truth** is equal to the probability of **they’re all telling the truth**, which is $\frac{8/27}{8/27+1/27}=8/9$.

Comment: You need some information (or assumption) on the prior probability that it's raining (granted, it's Seattle so you could assume $1$ for that).  Absent that...well, if the question was "is it raining liquid platinum?" then the answer would still be $0$ regardless of how many friends you asked.

Comment: You also need some assumption regarding the independence of the lies, though here I am reasonably certain that you intended to assume that the friends lie (or don't) independently of the truth and independently of each other.

Comment: The logic in the second method is just assigning equal prior probability $p=1/2$ to rain and dry. If you substitute in the first method result you can see it

Comment: @lulu yes I'm assuming their answers are independent, and let's say Seattle in the question is actually a parallel universe city which we don't know the prior probability of raining xD

Comment: You only need one person to tell the truth so wouldn't the probability that it is raining be $1-(\frac{1}{3})^3=\frac{26}{27}$?

Comment: As you can see from your (correct) first computation, knowledge of $p$ drives the calculation.  If you have no idea at all regarding the prior, you can take $\frac 12$ as a default guess, but you really can't imagine that it's terribly reliable.   Failing that, ask more friends.  Eventually the truth becomes evident from the pattern of responses (at least under sensible assumptions about the prior).

Comment: @lulu Why would the probability of rain in Seattle matter? Whether or not it is raining is observable.

Comment: @JohnDouma  Suppose you ask for an absurd event, like that a fair coin comes up $H$ a thousand times in a row.  Then having three people with a high probability of lying assure you that it is true will do little to convince you that it happened.

Comment: @JohnDouma  The OP's first approach is solid.  And it "behaves" right.  If $p=0$, so you are quite sure the event didn't happen, you get $0$ as you should.  And if $p=1$ you get $1$.

Comment: @lulu I don't understand that. If even one of them told the truth all the time and they observed a head a thousand times in a row and said so, then wouldn't that be the truth?

Comment: @JohnDouma  Sure, and that would emerge from the Bayesian computation.  The denominator is the probability of getting the responses one got.  Since everybody said the same thing that means that either it is raining and everyone is telling the truth or it isn't raining and everyone is lying.  If you knew that friend $\#2$ never lied then the second scenario couldn't happen.

Comment: @lulu That's where I am confused. The problem only gives us the probability that your friends lie or tell the truth. If we are to use Bayes' theorem then we would expect to get a different answer if they were asked if the Mariners won last night's game. From the information given in the problem I don't see how that would be different.

Comment: @JohnDouma  Again, the probabilities of the two scenarios is different, depending on your prior.  That changes both numerator and denominator.  Phrased informally, if I am quite sure a thing happened, then I am going to need overwhelming evidence to persuade me to change my view.  And if I think a thing is impossible, then having a few liars tell me it happened won't do much to persuade me.

Comment: @JohnDouma  If I ask my unreliable friends if some new pet is a dog (let's say dogs and cats are about equal odds), and I get three Yeses, I'll probably end up believing it.  That's the OP's second method, or the first with $p=\frac 12$.  If I ask whether it is a unicorn, the three Yeses won't do it for me.  It's far more likely that they are lying than that Zoology is entirely wrong and magical creatures are possible pets.

Comment: @Exodd I think you're right, and I understand it now: in my second approach, I'm assigning equal weights to event A(all telling truth) and B(all lying), instead I should multiply p and 1-p as weights.

Comment: @lulu I am not arguing over the concept. I am wondering if this is a Bayes' theorem problem. We don't know what book Raven is using or at in what section the problem was given.

Comment: @JohnDouma  Not sure how that matters...you can't get a numerical result here without a prior.  Perhaps that was the point of the exercise, or perhaps the point was to assign a variable to that and get a result in terms of that variable (as the OP did).  I hope the point wasn't to guess at a prior...that would be bad pedagogy in my opinion.

Comment: @lulu It matters because this is a math problem. If we are given that three persons lie with a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ without any other context then we assume the probabiity that an even occurred depends on nothing else but those probabilities. We don't consider what the claim is.

Comment: @JohnDouma  Sorry, that doesn't make sense.  The problem obviously depends on the underlying event...to pretend otherwise would just be wrong.    Now, of course we don't have the actual text.  Perhaps the writers explained what assumptions they wanted.

Comment: @Raven I believe the answer to your homework problem is no, considering how the question is worded and the comments by lulu. Assuming you copied the problem exactly, you are not being asked what the probability is; you are being asked if you can solve for the probability.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes you're right, given the information of the question we cannot calculate exact probability of it is actually raining in Seattle, but we can provide the intuition and formula to calculate it when we have necessary information (the historical probability of raining in Seattle).

it seems dumb, but the truth is: if we don't have the probability of raining in Seattle, we cannot calculate the probability of raining in Seattle xD.